# Convert numpy array with many dimensions into 2D array with nested numpy arrays

Tags: numpy

I would like to convert an array with many dimensions (more than 2) into a 2D array where other dimensions would be converted to nested stand-alone arrays.

So if I have an array like `numpy.arange(3 * 4 * 5 * 5 * 5).reshape((3, 4, 5, 5, 5))`, I would like to convert it to an array of shape `(3, 4)`, where each element would be an array of shape `(5, 5, 5)`. The dtype of the outer array would be `object`.

For example, for `np.arange(8).reshape((1, 1, 2, 2, 2))`, the output would be equivalent to:

```
a = np.ndarray(shape=(1,1), dtype=object)
a[0, 0] = np.arange(8).reshape((1, 1, 2, 2, 2))[0, 0, :, :, :]
```

How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: Could please show an example code where you show what you have already tried?

Comment: Can you show the expected output with, lets's say,  `np.arange(8).reshape((1, 1, 2, 2, 2))`? Your example is unnecessarily large.

Comment: Added expected output example.

Comment: A similar SO question, with a clever (though slower) answer using `frompyfunc`, [Force numpy to create array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064548/force-numpy-to-create-array-of-objects/49104269#49104269)

Answer (score 1):

We can reshape and assign elements from the *regular* array into the output object dtype array in a single loop that seems to be a tad faster than with two loops, like so -

```
def reshape_approach(a):
    m,n = a.shape[:2]
    a.shape = (m*n,) + a.shape[2:]
    out = np.empty((m*n),dtype=object)
    for i in range(m*n):
        out[i] = a[i]
    out.shape = (m,n)
    a.shape = (m,n) + a.shape[1:]
    return out
```

**Runtime test**

Other approach(es) -

```
# @Scotty1-'s soln
def simply_assign(a):
    m,n = a.shape[:2]
    out = np.empty((m,n),dtype=object)
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            out[i,j] = a[i,j]
    return out
```

Timings -

```
In [154]: m,n = 300,400
     ...: a = np.arange(m * n * 5 * 5 * 5).reshape((m,n, 5, 5, 5))

In [155]: %timeit simply_assign(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 39.4 ms per loop

In [156]: %timeit reshape_approach(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 32.9 ms per loop
```

With `7D` data -

```
In [160]: m,n,p,q = 30,40,30,40
     ...: a = np.arange(m * n *p * q * 5 * 5 * 5).reshape((m,n,p,q, 5, 5, 5))

In [161]: %timeit simply_assign(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 421 µs per loop

In [162]: %timeit reshape_approach(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 316 µs per loop
```

Comment: Good solution. but imho too complicated for a simple task, if efficiency is not essential for survival. What could be even faster is doing `x.reshape(-1)` and then use strides to avoid loops completely. I'll take a look into this later on.

Comment: @Scotty1- Well OP is asking for performance, so I don't see why few extra steps would hurt :)

Comment: The reshape loop could be replaced by `out[:] = list(a)`, though the timing is essentially the same.

Comment: @hpaulj Yup, tried that, but that's noticeably slower.

Comment: @Mitar What do you mean assign to shape?

Comment: I didn't know that you can do `out.shape = (m,n)`. I always thought you have to call `reshape`.

Comment: @Mitar Yeah, that's just a shorter alternative to reshape arrays in-place.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your hint Mitar. This is how it should look like using `dtype=np.object` arrays:

```
outer_array = np.empty((x.shape[0], x.shape[1]), dtype=np.object)
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
        outer_array[i, j] = x[i, j]
```

Looping may not be the most *efficient* way to do it, but there is afaik no vectorized operation for this task.

(Using some more reshaping, this should be even faster than Divakar's solution: ;)) ---> No, Divakar is faster.... Nice solution Divakar!

```
def advanced_reshape_solution(x):
    m, n = x.shape[:2]
    sub_arr_size = np.prod(x.shape[2:])
    out_array = np.empty((m * n), dtype=object)
    x_flat_view = x.reshape(-1)
    for i in range(m*n):
        out_array[i] = x_flat_view[i * sub_arr_size:(i + 1) * sub_arr_size].reshape(x.shape[2:])
    return out_array.reshape((m, n))
```

Comment: You can store a numpy array as an object in an array with dtype object.

Comment: Is that so? Then give me a second to update my answer.

Comment: This works. But only with 5 dimensional arrays. How can you get a subarray for arbitrary number of dimensions?

Comment: @Mitar Updated my solution.

Comment: Oh, this looks simpler than expected. :-)

Comment: If it is working: I am glad that I was able to help. :) If it is not yet working: I'll be able to respond in about 2 hours and will then try to solve your problem.